# SQL duplicate data for excel dynamic table

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

First thanks for reading me and sorry for my bad english.

I have the following code on sql server 2008 r2

```
SELECT FA960.*,
       UMCONVPZ.UMFR,
       UMCONVPZ.UMCONF AS Piezas,
       UMCONVPL.UMCONF AS PL, 
       UMCONVCJ.UMCONF AS Cajas
  FROM FA960 FA960
  JOIN UMCONV UMCONVPZ ON FA960.RECURV = UMCONVPZ.UMRESR 
  JOIN UMCONV UMCONVPL ON FA960.RECURV = UMCONVPL.UMRESR 
  JOIN UMCONV UMCONVCJ ON FA960.RECURV = UMCONVCJ.UMRESR
 WHERE FA960.RMUMSR = UMCONVPZ.UMFR
   AND UMCONVPZ.UMTO = 'PZ' 
   AND UMCONVPL.UMTO = 'PL' 
   AND UMCONVCJ.UMTO = 'CJ'
```

Output:

```
PERAA  PERMM  NUMLI  RMDESC    RMUMSR   RECURV  RMMIS2  RMWGHT  RMNETW  CONCA  Cont_x_CjPz  PesoNt_x_WhPz  PesoLg_WhLPz PesoNt_x_WhCj   PesoLg_WhLCj    PESOPZNT    PESOPZBR    Pz_Emb  Cj_Emb  UMFR    Piezas  PL  Cajas
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2010   1      40     MAYONESA  LIMONES  SQUEEZE  12 OZ  CJ      405300  12     4.460000     3.840000       12.000000    12.0000000000000000000000   0.3200000000000000000000    0.3716660000000000000000    3.8400000000000000000000    4.4599920000000000000000    0.320000000000  0.371666666666  112476.000000   9373.000000 CJ  12.000000   130.000000  130.000000
2010   1      40     MAYONESA  LIMONES  SQUEEZE  12 OZ  CJ      405300  12     4.460000     3.840000       12.000000    12.0000000000000000000000   0.3200000000000000000000    0.3716660000000000000000    3.8400000000000000000000    4.4599920000000000000000    0.320000000000  0.371666666666  112476.000000   9373.000000 CJ  12.000000   130.000000  12.000000
```

This is a view, the UMCONV table is a conversion of measures that goes from palets to boxes, to pieces.

Now my problem is that CJ (Boxes) go to both PZ (Pieces) and PL (Palets) thus making me a duplicate entry that bring "trash data".

```
SELECT [UMFR]
      ,[UMTO]
      ,[UMRESR]
      ,[UMWHSE]
      ,[UMLOCN]
      ,[UMVNNO]
      ,[UMSEQN]
      ,[UMCONF]
      ,[UMCALC]
      ,[UMQYF1]
      ,[UMQYT1]
      ,[UMQYF2]
      ,[UMQYT2]
      ,[UMQYF3]
      ,[UMQYT3]
      ,[UMQYF4]
      ,[UMQYT4]
      ,[UMQYF5]
      ,[UMQYT5]
      ,[UMDTMT]
      ,[UMBLNK]
  FROM [LOGISTICA].[dbo].[UMCONV]
```

```
UMFR    UMTO    UMRESR  UMWHSE  UMLOCN  UMVNNO  UMSEQN  UMCONF  UMCALC  UMQYF1  UMQYT1  UMQYF2  UMQYT2  UMQYF3  UMQYT3  UMQYF4  UMQYT4  UMQYF5  UMQYT5  UMDTMT  UMBLNK
PL  CJ  405300              1   130.000000  M   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    1020627 
CJ  PL  405300              1   130.000000  D   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    1020627 
PZ  CJ  405300              1   12.000000   D   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    1041016 
CJ  PZ  405300              1   12.000000   M   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    1041016
```

Any idea of how to solve it? so far I think force it to convert and do a rock paper scissors

Any other idea?

This is the

Comment: So the View is intended to have Rows that contain all the item's info from FA960 and then its conversion factors from Pieces to Boxes and to Palets, which are all contained within UMCONV?

Comment: Correct, but is having a duplicate register always, while this doesnt affect the data at all... its ugly for the administration department.

Comment: Please don't use tabs to separate data that you post to SO - really makes a mess of the formatting.

Comment: @OMG Ponies I am sorry whats the correct way to put a table on SO? So I dont make the mistake again in the future.

Comment: Data separated by tabs -- `\t` causes grief when formatting on SO.  If possible, please replace them before posting to SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How does this work for you:

```
SELECT DISTINCT f.*,
       f.RMUMSR as De,
       COALESCE((SELECT UMCONF FROM UMCONV WHERE UMRESR = f.RECURV AND UMFR = f.RMUMSR AND UMTO = 'PZ'), 1) AS Piezas,
       COALESCE((SELECT UMCONF FROM UMCONV WHERE UMRESR = f.RECURV AND UMFR = f.RMUMSR AND UMTO = 'PL'), 1) AS Palet,
       COALESCE((SELECT UMCONF FROM UMCONV WHERE UMRESR = f.RECURV AND UMFR = f.RMUMSR AND UMTO = 'CJ'), 1) AS Cajas
FROM FA960 f
```

Comment: Edited to correct the sub query and added COALESCE to return 1 for the conversion factor column that is equal to De.

Comment: p You where faster than me, I am sorry what does the COALESCE does and they 1?

Comment: @Enrique: Haha Yeah I just realized I wrote the subqueries incorrectly. Without the additional filter on the UMFR column it will return more than one item. COALESCE is a SQL Server fucntion that returns the first argument that is not NULL. In this case, I added it so the conversion factor to the identical unit would be 1. I figured that would be most logical, but you can replace 1 if another value is more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using DISTINCT:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       FA960.*,
       UMCONVPZ.UMFR,
       UMCONVPZ.UMCONF AS Piezas,
       UMCONVPL.UMCONF AS PL, 
       UMCONVCJ.UMCONF AS Cajas
  FROM FA960 FA960
  JOIN UMCONV UMCONVPZ ON UMCONVPZ.UMRESR = FA960.RECURV 
                      AND UMCONVPZ.UMFR = FA960.RMUMSR
                      AND UMCONVPZ.UMTO = 'PZ' 
  JOIN UMCONV UMCONVPL ON UMCONVPL.UMRESR = FA960.RECURV 
                      AND UMCONVPL.UMTO = 'PL'
  JOIN UMCONV UMCONVCJ ON UMCONVCJ.UMRESR = FA960.RECURV
                      AND UMCONVCJ.UMTO = 'CJ'
```

It's tough to say without knowing more about the data.

Comment: I just try your solution and still bring a second register, in which is trying to do the CJ - to PL and other with CJ to PZ

Comment: @Enrique: Then there are other fields that have different values - I'm skeptical that the "CJ" relationship is your only issue.  We need to know more detail about your data to help you solve the issue.

Comment: @Enrique: Address a comment to me, like how I am to you, when you're finished editing.

Comment: Done, I added some result, and the conversion table.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: He meant include the @ part so it'll show up in his inbox.